# linux execute command remotely

Tags: linux, command

How do I execute command/script on a remote Linux box?
Say, I want to do `service tomcat start` on box b from box a.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I guess `ssh` is the best secured way for this, for example :

```
ssh -OPTIONS -p SSH_PORT user@remote_server "remote_command1; remote_command2; remote_script.sh"
```

where the OPTIONS have to be deployed according to your specific needs (for example, binding to ipv4 only) and your remote command could be starting your tomcat daemon.

**Note**:
If you do not want to be prompt at every ssh run, please also have a look to ssh-agent, and optionally to `keychain` if your system allows it. Key is... to understand the ssh keys exchange process. Please take a careful look to ssh_config (i.e. the ssh client config file) and sshd_config (i.e. the ssh server config file). Configuration filenames depend on your system, anyway you'll find them somewhere like `/etc/sshd_config`. Ideally, pls do not run ssh as root obviously but as a specific user on both sides, servers and client.

Some extra docs over the source project main pages :

**ssh and ssh-agent**
man ssh

http://www.snailbook.com/index.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

**keychain**
http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/keychain-guide.xml
an older tuto in French (by myself :-) but might be useful too :
http://hornetbzz.developpez.com/tutoriels/debian/ssh/keychain/

Answer (score 32):

```
 ssh user@machine 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
```

or you can just

```
 ssh user@machine "remote command to run"
```

Comment: Is there anyway to enter the password on the same line? That way my script won't get stopped by the prompt.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to deal with security and want to make it as exposed (aka "convenient") as possible for short term, and|or don't have ssh/telnet or key generation on all your hosts, you can can hack a one-liner together with netcat.  Write a command to your target computer's port over the network and it will run it.  Then you can block access to that port to a few "trusted" users or wrap it in a script that only allows certain commands to run.  And use a low privilege user.

## on the server

`mkfifo /tmp/netfifo; nc -lk 4201 0</tmp/netfifo | bash -e &>/tmp/netfifo`

This one liner reads whatever string you send into that port and pipes it into bash to be executed.  stderr & stdout are dumped back into netfifo and sent back to the connecting host via nc.

## on the client

To run a command remotely:
`echo "ls" | nc HOST 4201`