# How to cd on remote server via SSH bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

I have a bash script I'm using to connect to a remote server via ssh. That works, however I want the script to immediately pass the command of cd /some/dir after connecting. That doesn't seem to be working. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "SSHing.."
ssh -i ~/.ssh/some-site.pem xxx@yyy.com
cd /some/dir        
read
```

How can I have the cd command be executed right after SSH connection is established?

Comment: This thread [linux-execute-command-remotely][1] might be helpful to you. Did you check it?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162568/linux-execute-command-remotely

Answer (score 10):

There are two easy ways to execute commands via SSH from inside the script:

1) `ssh user@host 'command'`

2)

```
ssh user@host <<<EOF
command1
command2
<...>
commandn
EOF
```

Comment: #2 gives the error `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`

Comment: @Click Upvote see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal for a similar problem, I wouldn't explain better.

Comment: I was getting a '-bash: line 1: EOF: command not found' error but changed <<<EOF to <<EOF and everything worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Normally you'd just edit your ~/.profile on the remote machine.

If that is not an option, you could do something like this:

```
ssh -t theserver.com 'cd /some/dir && bash -i'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command

```
ssh user@watevr <the_cmd_to_be_executed>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
ssh abc@hostname :/pathto/specific directory
```