# BASH alias running a script on another server

Tags: bash

This is either rather simple or impossible, however I can't seem to get a go with it. I'm trying to run a script located on a remote server and I have the following alias in my .bashrc:

```
alias fin='sh username@host.co.uk:~/scripts/finder.sh'
```

I have set up SSH key authentication to that host, however I am getting the following error:

```
sh: 0: Can't openusername@host.co.uk:~/scripts/finder.sh
```

Can someone please help, thanks :)

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162568/linux-execute-command-remotely

Comment: As an aside, classic `sh` does not support tilde expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot refer to a remote script as if it were a file name. You can use `ssh` but the syntax is slightly different.

```
ssh username@host.co.uk scripts/finder.sh
```

As an aside, functions are often better than aliases.

```
fin () {
    ssh username@host.co.uk scripts/finder.sh "$@"
}
```

The `"$@"` is for passing arguments. If the script takes no parameters, it can be omitted.

Comment: Updated with an example.

Answer (score 1):

`alias fin='ssh username@host.co.uk /home/username/scripts/finder.sh'`

you need to make sure `finder.sh` has execute permissions and runs locally on host.co.uk as user `username`

Comment: The remote shell will run from the remote user's home directory; hard-coding the full path is redundant and involves some speculation here.

Comment: For me on mac in bash shell it was resolving to `/Users/username/scripts/finder.sh`

Comment: @sdayal, it bases that on a lookup on the actual user's home directory, so it'll be appropriate for the system at hand. `/home/username` is convention for traditional unix-family operating systems, so it's presumably such a system that the OP is SSHing to.